# Web API (C#) copia de arquivos diretório externo

Tags: c#, api

Tenho uma Web Api em C# .net framework. Nessa aplicação tenho um método responsável por copiar alguns arquivos para um diretório local, onde tenho meu frontEnd. O problema que estou tendo é que meu web service (depois de hospedado), não consegue copiar os arquivos do diretório de rede, o que não acontecia quando a aplicação estava local. Existe alguma configuração que eu tenha que fazer no meu servidor IIS para que os arquivos sejam copiados igual acontecia no server local? se ajudar a aplicação não retorna mensagens de erro ao tentar copiar os arquivos.

Comment: precisa ver se o usuário que está rodando a aplicação ou o *application pool* no `IIS` tem acesso para copiar os arquivos

Comment: Pelo que vi minha aplicação está usando a DefaultAppPool (quando tento usar alguma outra da erro). Existe alguma possibilidade de dar permissão para ela?

Comment: Sim é possível. Como o DefaultAppPool é uma conta local da máquina, seria interessante adicioná-la a um grupo que tenha permissão, e as máquinas devem estar no mesmo domínio.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito. Teoricamente eu teria que dar permissão para pasta no meu diretório para esse usuário? se sim como? porque quando eu tento fazer da forma convencional ele não encontra o usuário.

Comment: Para os sites que uso na empresa que precisam acessar pastas da rede, criamos um ApplicationPool separado e colocamos na identidade um usuário de domínio que tem acesso na pasta/servidor de rede, acho que esse é o jeito mais simples.

Comment: então acho que tenho um problema. Basicamente nenhum de nossos servidores estão no domínio. talvez esse seja o problema afinal.

Comment: então pra você acessar uma pasta de outra máquina você deve precisar de um usuário/senha que foi configurado no outro computador certo? nesse caso um drive mapeado pode ajudar.. o problema é que esse mapeamento só existe para o usuário logado, então pode ser necessário mapear o drive ao iniciar sua aplicação no `IIS`, no código

Comment: Não consegui resolver o problema no próprio **IIS**. A solução que encontrei foi configurar um **ftp** no servidor onde eu busco as imagens e alterar minha **web api** para olhar o **ftp**.

Comment: Entendi. Seu cenário é bem específico, porque em geral como as máquinas estão no mesmo domínio é mais simples. Acho que foi uma boa solução